# Why does adding dropout layers work on validation set, but not on test set?

Tags: validation, testing, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm working on a convolutional neural network in TensorFlow and having trouble with the dropout layers. As recommended, I'm passing a keep_probability placeholder to the graph and setting the value to 0.5 during training, and 1.0 during validation and testing. When observing the training process, the results are good for the validation set. However, when I test the network after training, the network fails.

UPDATE: When I say that the network fails, I mean that the network no longer segments the images correctly. During validation the network gets an mIoU of around 80%, but when testing it falls down to around 40% and classifies all the pixels into just one of the classes. Before the dropout layers were added, both validation and test set got an mIoU of around 80%.

I do not understand why the network is failing on the test set when it works on the validation set?

I've added the code for training, testing and for the graph itself.

Code for training the network:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
   #Probablitity that the neuron's output will be kept during dropout
    keep_probability = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep_probabilty")

    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)

    images, labels = Inputs.datasetInputs(image_filenames, label_filenames, FLAGS.batch_size)
    val_images, val_labels = Inputs.datasetInputs(val_image_filenames, val_label_filenames, FLAGS.batch_size)

    train_data_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.image_h, FLAGS.image_w, 3])
    train_labels_node = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.image_h, FLAGS.image_w, 1])
    phase_train = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='phase_train')

    logits = model.inference(train_data_node, phase_train, FLAGS.batch_size, keep_probability) #tensor, nothing calculated yet
    loss = model.cal_loss(logits, train_labels_node)
    # Build a Graph that trains the model with one batch of examples and updates the model parameters.
     train_op = model.train(loss, global_step)

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

    """ Starting iterations to train the network """
    for step in range(startstep, startstep + FLAGS.max_steps):
        image_batch ,label_batch = sess.run(fetches=[images, labels])
        # since we still use mini-batches in eval, still set bn-layer phase_train = True
        feed_dict = {
          train_data_node: image_batch,
          train_labels_node: label_batch,
          phase_train: True,
          keep_probability: 0.5
        }

        _, loss_value = sess.run(fetches=[train_op, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)

        if step % 10 == 0:
          num_examples_per_step = FLAGS.batch_size
          examples_per_sec = num_examples_per_step / duration
          sec_per_batch = float(duration)

          # eval current training batch pre-class accuracy
          pred = sess.run(fetches=logits, feed_dict=feed_dict)

          Utils.per_class_acc(pred, label_batch)



        if step % 100 == 0 or (step + 1) == FLAGS.max_steps:
          """ Validate training by running validation dataset """
          total_val_loss = 0.0
          hist = np.zeros((FLAGS.num_class, FLAGS.num_class))
          for test_step in range(TEST_ITER):
            val_images_batch, val_labels_batch = sess.run(fetches=[val_images, val_labels])
            feed_dict = {
              train_data_node: val_images_batch,
              train_labels_node: val_labels_batch,
              phase_train: True,
              keep_probability: 1.0 #During testing droput should be turned off -> 100% chance for keeping variable
            }
            _val_loss, _val_pred = sess.run(fetches=[loss, logits], feed_dict=feed_dict)

 (...)
```

Code for testing the network:

```
keep_probability = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep_probabilty")

  image_filenames, label_filenames = Inputs.get_filename_list(FLAGS.test_dir)
  test_data_node = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[testing_batch_size, FLAGS.image_h, FLAGS.image_w, FLAGS.image_c])  #360, 480, 3
  test_labels_node = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[FLAGS.test_batch_size, FLAGS.image_h, FLAGS.image_w, 1])

  phase_train = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='phase_train')

  logits = model.inference(test_data_node, phase_train, testing_batch_size, keep_probability)
  loss = model.cal_loss(logits, test_labels_node)
  pred = tf.argmax(logits, dimension=3)

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Load checkpoint
    saver.restore(sess, FLAGS.model_ckpt_dir)

    images, labels = Inputs.get_all_test_data(image_filenames, label_filenames)
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
    hist = np.zeros((FLAGS.num_class, FLAGS.num_class))
    step=0
    for image_batch, label_batch  in zip(images, labels):
      feed_dict = { #maps graph elements to values
        test_data_node: image_batch,
        test_labels_node: label_batch,
        phase_train: False,
        keep_probability: 1.0 #During testing droput should be turned off -> 100% chance for keeping variable
      }

      dense_prediction, im = sess.run(fetches=[logits, pred], feed_dict=feed_dict)
(...)
```

The graph:

```
def inference(images, phase_train, batch_size, keep_prob):
  conv1_1 = conv_layer_with_bn(images, [7, 7, images.get_shape().as_list()[3], 64], phase_train, name="conv1_1")
  conv1_2 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv1_1, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, name="conv1_2")
  dropout1 = tf.layers.dropout(conv1_2, rate=(1-keep_prob), training=phase_train, name="dropout1")
  pool1, pool1_indices = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(dropout1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                                                    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool1')
  conv2_1 = conv_layer_with_bn(pool1, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, name="conv2_1")
  conv2_2 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv2_1, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, name="conv2_2")
  dropout2 = tf.layers.dropout(conv2_2, rate=(1-keep_prob), training=phase_train, name="dropout2")
  pool2, pool2_indices = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(dropout2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                                                    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool2')
  conv3_1 = conv_layer_with_bn(pool2, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, name="conv3_1")
  conv3_2 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv3_1, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, name="conv3_2")
  conv3_3 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv3_2, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, name="conv3_3")
  dropout3 = tf.layers.dropout(conv3_3, rate=(1-keep_prob), training=phase_train, name="dropout3")
  pool3, pool3_indices = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(dropout3, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                                                    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool3')
  conv4_1 = conv_layer_with_bn(pool3, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, name="conv4_1")
  conv4_2 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv4_1, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, name="conv4_2")
  conv4_3 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv4_2, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, name="conv4_3")
  dropout4 = tf.layers.dropout(conv4_3, rate=(1-keep_prob), training=phase_train, name="dropout4")
  pool4, pool4_indices = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(dropout4, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                                                    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool4')
  conv5_1 = conv_layer_with_bn(pool4, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, name="conv5_1")
  conv5_2 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv5_1, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, name="conv5_2")
  conv5_3 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv5_2, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, name="conv5_3")
  dropout5 = tf.layers.dropout(conv5_3, rate=(1-keep_prob), training=phase_train, name="dropout5")
  pool5, pool5_indices = tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax(dropout5, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                                                    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool5')
  """ End of encoder """

  """ Start decoder """
  dropout5_decode = tf.layers.dropout(pool5, rate=(1-keep_prob), training=phase_train, name="dropout5_decode")
  upsample5 = deconv_layer(dropout5_decode, [2, 2, 64, 64], [batch_size, FLAGS.image_h//16, FLAGS.image_w//16, 64], 2, "up5")
  conv_decode5_1 = conv_layer_with_bn(upsample5, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, True, name="conv_decode5_1")
  conv_decode5_2 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv_decode5_1, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, True, name="conv_decode5_2")
  conv_decode5_3 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv_decode5_2, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, True, name="conv_decode5_3")

  dropout4_decode = tf.layers.dropout(conv_decode5_3, rate=(1-keep_prob), training=phase_train, name="dropout4_decode")
  upsample4 = deconv_layer(dropout4_decode, [2, 2, 64, 64], [batch_size, FLAGS.image_h//8, FLAGS.image_w//8, 64], 2, "up4")
  conv_decode4_1 = conv_layer_with_bn(upsample4, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, True, name="conv_decode4_1")
  conv_decode4_2 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv_decode4_1, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, True, name="conv_decode4_2")
  conv_decode4_3 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv_decode4_2, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, True, name="conv_decode4_3")

  dropout3_decode = tf.layers.dropout(conv_decode4_3, rate=(1-keep_prob), training=phase_train, name="dropout3_decode")
  upsample3 = deconv_layer(dropout3_decode, [2, 2, 64, 64], [batch_size, FLAGS.image_h//4, FLAGS.image_w//4, 64], 2, "up3")
  conv_decode3_1 = conv_layer_with_bn(upsample3, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, True, name="conv_decode3_1")
  conv_decode3_2 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv_decode3_1, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, True, name="conv_decode3_2")
  conv_decode3_3 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv_decode3_2, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, True, name="conv_decode3_3")

  dropout2_decode = tf.layers.dropout(conv_decode3_3, rate=(1-keep_prob), training=phase_train, name="dropout2_decode")
  upsample2= deconv_layer(dropout2_decode, [2, 2, 64, 64], [batch_size, FLAGS.image_h//2, FLAGS.image_w//2, 64], 2, "up2")
  conv_decode2_1 = conv_layer_with_bn(upsample2, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, True, name="conv_decode2_1")
  conv_decode2_2 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv_decode2_1, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, True, name="conv_decode2_2")

  dropout1_decode = tf.layers.dropout(conv_decode2_2, rate=(1-keep_prob), training=phase_train, name="dropout1_deconv")
  upsample1 = deconv_layer(dropout1_decode, [2, 2, 64, 64], [batch_size, FLAGS.image_h, FLAGS.image_w, 64], 2, "up1")
  conv_decode1_1 = conv_layer_with_bn(upsample1, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, True, name="conv_decode1_1")
  conv_decode1_2 = conv_layer_with_bn(conv_decode1_1, [7, 7, 64, 64], phase_train, True, name="conv_decode1_2")
  """ End of decoder """

  """ Start Classify """
  # output predicted class number (2)
  with tf.variable_scope('conv_classifier') as scope:
    shape=[1, 1, 64, FLAGS.num_class]
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=shape, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(), #orthogonal_initializer()
                                           wd=None)

    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(conv_decode1_2, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [FLAGS.num_class], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    conv_classifier = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases, name=scope.name) #tf.nn.bias_add is an activation function. Simple add that specifies 1-D tensor bias
    #logit = conv_classifier = prediction
  return conv_classifier
```

Comment: We do not know what you mean by "the network fails", please clarify that point.

Comment: Why is it related to drop out ? Does it work without ?

Comment: Sorry about that! I'm segmenting images into two classes: "not bulding" and "building". When testing the network, all the pixels are classified as "not building". This does not happen during validation. Before I added the dropout layers the validation and test dataset gave similar results.

Comment: same issue. any ideas?

Comment: The idea behind drop out is to penalize your training model, by training it with keep_prob fraction of actual size. This makes sure that each weight parameter is sufficiently trained. We do not drop out during testing because we want to test the weights that we trained during training phase

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out that my issue came from problems with batch normalization not being implemented correctly.

The issue was that I did not update the moving_mean and moving_variance   correctly. This is pointed out in the TensorFlow [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm) for batch_norm:

> Note: when training, the moving_mean and moving_variance need to be
>   updated. By default the update ops are placed in
>   tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, so they need to be added as a dependency to
>   the train_op.

My code, therefore, looks like this:

```
def training(loss):

    global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)

    #This motif is needed to hook up the batch_norm updates to the training
    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        if(FLAGS.optimizer == "SGD"):
            print("Running with SGD optimizer")
            optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
        elif(FLAGS.optimizer == "adam"):
            print("Running with adam optimizer")
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001)
        elif(FLAGS.optimizer == "adagrad"):
            print("Running with adagrad optimizer")
            optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01)
        else:
            raise ValueError("optimizer was not recognized.")

        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=global_step)
    return train_op, global_step
```

Full implementation of my network can be seen here: https://github.com/mathildor/TF-SegNet